# Sorting column data such that numbers come first then alphanumeric in order explained below

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting

Need to sort data such that if list of values in a column are like below,

*column*

```
12A
12B
3
4
12H
RR
```

then after sorting and aggregating i need its output as below,

*new_agg_col*

```
3,4,12A,12B,12H,RR
```

I am using listagg function to aggregate data in one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT '12A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12H' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RR' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT LISTAGG( value, ',' )
         WITHIN GROUP (
           ORDER BY TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '^\d+' ) ) NULLS LAST,
                    REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\D.*' )
         ) AS ordered_list
FROM   table_name;
```

**Output**:

```
ORDERED_LIST
------------------
3,4,12A,12B,12H,RR
```

Comment: works fine with the dataset quoted, but i have some more scenarios in my subject case. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the table or query that you are performing the LISTAGG you can use regex to extract a new field that has just the numbers and another that has the letters then in the ORDER BY of the LISTAGG you can use those columns for ordering.

I don't have time for the full code right now so let me know if you need it.

Without testing I believe those regex are

```
'([0-9]+)'

'([A-Za-z]+)'
```